# Use Snowflake Connector on Python 3.12

Tags: python, package, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-connection, python-3.12

I have just switched from Python version 3.11.6 to 3.12.0
Previously it was possible for me to run the following script (I installed snowflake-python-connector):

```
import snowflake

# Connection to Snowflake
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='your_user',
    password='your_password',
    account='your_account',
    warehouse='your_warehouse',
    role='your_role'
)
```

But now with the new Python version I receive the error message: "AttributeError: module 'snowflake' has no attribute 'connector'"
I could not figure out how to fix it. I know I can just go back to Python version 3.11.6 but is it also possible to use the snowflake connector on the 3.12.0 version?

I have reinstalled the packages snowflake and snowflake-python-connector, that did not help. Also I found the hint to use "import snowflake.connector" instead of "import snowflake" but it did not work for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `snowflake-connector-python` supports `Python 3.12`

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

**If you have both `snowflake` and `snowflake-connector-python` installed in your virtual environment you will get**

`"AttributeError: module 'snowflake' has no attribute 'connector'"`

***You need to uninstall snowflake***

```
pip uninstall snowflake
```

Then:

```
import snowflake.connector

# Connection to Snowflake
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='your_user',
    password='your_password',
    account='your_account',
    warehouse='your_warehouse',
    role='your_role'
)
```

Comment: When I try to install the latest snowflake version I get the following error:

ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.3.0 Requires-Python <3.11,>=3.8; 0.4.0 Requires-Python <3.11,>=3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-legacy (from snowflake) (from versions: none)

When I check the snowflake version I'm using via "pip3 show snowflake" it tells me I'm at version 0.0.4, could this be the issue?

Comment: @Theki please see the edit. This was the catch. Both `snowflake` and `snowflake.connector` packages should not be present in the same virtual environment.

Comment: I deinstalled the snowflake package and have snowflake-connector-python 3.5.0. But when I want to run "import snowflake.connector" I get the error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package

Comment: Thanks for coming back.. What I suggest create a new virtual environment from scratch, then `pip install snowflake-connector-python` in this fresh virtual environment. Then do `import snowflake.connector`. I was able to import successfully on my `python 3.12`.

Comment: I was able to run it now, thank you!